# How to embed SPList to a custom application page?

Tags: 2010, list, development, splist, spgridview

I have a custom central admin list and would like to insert it to a custom application page in a way that would make it look *exactly* like it does if you access the list via its URL - i.e. it should support sorting, filtering, item selection, paging etc.

In my current solution, I bind the list data to `SPGridView` and it works fine - however, as `SPGridView` doesn't support auto generation of columns, I have to provide a lot of extra code to handle things like sorting, style, paging, filtering etc. - stuff that works out of the box if I navigate to the list via its SharePoint URL. Another method I found mentioned is first creating a web part and inserting the list there, then showing the web part in my application page - is this the only alternative or is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually add XSLTListViewWebPart control in your Application Page and that should work exactly the same as list default page..

See [XSLTListViewWebpart in Sharepoint 2010 Uncovered](http://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/xsltlistviewwebpart-in-sharepoint-2010-uncovered/)

[Download the XSLTListViewWebPart Declaration](http://yoursandmyideas.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/samplexslt.doc), Set appropriate properties and you are good to go..

Comment: Seems that using this web part in application pages is not recommended and can cause various problems: [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/50001/4387)